# How to perform multiplication in date (datetimeoffset format)

Tags: c#, datetime

I have following 3 fields
`startingdate`,  `expirydate`,  `number of months`

```
startingdate = DateTimeOffset.Now;
```

and number of months, *say `24` months*

How to calculate `expirydate = ?`

Can anybody give me an idea?

Comment: Really? You couldn't find AddMonths?

Comment: Ooo,why i didn't see that,...

Comment: actually am a beginner

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need multiplication in this case - just addition, specifying the units:

```
DateTimeOffset startDate = DateTimeOffset.Now;
DateTimeOffset expiryDate = startDate.AddMonths(months);
```

Two things to note:

- Date and time arithmetic can be odd. In your example case it's less likely to be odd than normal, as you've got 2 years, so the only corner case is adding 2 years to February 29th and getting February 28th; normally you'd need to consider (say) adding 1 month to August 31st and getting September 30th. In other words, just because two expiry dates are the same doesn't mean they came from the same start date.
- You might want to consider using `DateTimeOffset.UtcNow` and doing everything in UTC, rather than using the local time zone. Using `DateTimeOffset` instead of `DateTime` protects you from time zone problems to *some* extent, but keeping everything in UTC is clearer.
- If you *really* mean you have dates rather than dates and times, you might want to explicitly use midnight... it's unfortunate that .NET doesn't have any "date-only" type. You might want to consider using my [Noda Time](http://nodatime.org) which is designed to make things rather clearer than the BCL API.